# GET mapping works but POST, PUT and DELETE have status 405 (in spring-boot Restful api)

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, web-services, intellij-idea

I use Intellij idea and I created a spring-boot project. My problem is with request methods, when I use GET method, it works but POST,PUT and DELETE methods throw that damn Whitelabel Error Page!!
The error content is :

> "There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
>   Request method 'GET' not supported"

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class CustomerInquiryController {

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String getMessage(){
        return "msg is fetched!";
    }

    @PostMapping("/post")
    public String addMessage(){
        return "msg is added!";
    }

    @PutMapping("/put")
    public String editMessage(){
        return "msg is edited!";
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/del")
    public String deleteMessage(){
        return "msg is deleted!";
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to access those endpoints? Are you using postman? What url are you using?

Comment: Try replacing `@RequestMapping("/")` with `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})`

If that doesn't work you might need a `@ResponseBody` or `@ResponseStatus` in there

Comment: No matter which app I use, postman, arc, or chrome. It is very strange that it worked!!! with adding "method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}" to class annotation. I used this annotation before my method and it didn't work.

Comment: For me this code works with Spring Boot `2.1.7.RELEASE` and I can consume those endpoints using postman.

Comment: Why are you putting separate paths on the controllers? The purpose of verbs is not to have to repeat that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with adding "method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST}" to class annotation according to [cardouken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7360568/cardouken)'s comment. Earlier, I used this annotation before my method but it didn't work. It is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser only makes `GET` requests (and `POST` if through a form), you can't test other request methods from your browser. Use `postman`, `curl`, `wget` or a similar tool to access those endpoints.

Comment: Spring comes with a verb filter OOTB that supports the other verbs; in particular, I've had success using Thymeleaf and just saying `method="DELETE"`, which the default Boot starters configure to add the hidden verb.

Comment: @chrylis but that would be Thymeleaf specific, involving generated Javascript (or some other skullduggery). Since he said he's getting the white label error page, I assumed he's just trying all the endpoints in the browser, not understanding the difference between request methods.

Comment: No JavaScript (and I'm pretty sure the JSP taglib does it too), but it is [part of the main `spring-web` module](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java).

Comment: @chrylis interesting. Didn't know there was a filter mechanism for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `curl -X POST http://<YOUR_HOST>:<PORT>/post` in your command line. If this returns `msg is added!` your POST is working.  Try using alternate tool or form post to then post data.

Replace  with hostname or ip you are using and  with port number before running the command.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually, you don't even need a `@RequestMapping("/")`.

This would have done the job:

```
@RestController
public class CustomerInquiryController {

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String getMessage(){
        return "msg is fetched!";
    }

    @PostMapping("/post")
    public String addMessage(){
        return "msg is added!";
    }

    // .. other mappings..
}
```

Answer (score -2):

HTML forms support GET and POST. 
HTML5 at one point added PUT/DELETE, but those were dropped.

Comment: It's the programmer who decides which action is taken when a form is submitted.